# Java 17 | Need Help to update to Gson 2.9.0 and disableJdkUnsafe

Tags: java, gson, java-17

I'm trying to Update my Gson version to 2.9.0 and disableJdkUnsafe,
Can I get help with below error. This is from a broken test when I updated my GsonBuilder.
The test coverage of my project is 60%. How can I identify potential breaks due to disableJdkUnsafe and how can I resolve these issues ?

com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Unable to create instance of class java.time.LocalDate; usage of JDK Unsafe is disabled. Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type, adding a no-args constructor, or enabling usage of JDK Unsafe may fix this problem.

Comment: Did you consider implementing a type adapter for `java.time.LocalDate`?